# What is the best solution to smoothly hiding magento messages with click on a close button?

Tags: magento2.4, messages

I customized message.js for smoothly messages hiding - now messages will be smoothly hidden afters 5 seconds. Here is the code.

```
define([
'jquery',
'uiComponent',
'underscore',
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
], function ($, Component, _, customerData,ko) {
'use strict';

return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        cookieMessages: [],
        messages: [],
        selector: '.page.messages .message',
        listens: {
            isHidden: 'onHiddenChange'
        }
    },
    /** @inheritdoc */
    initialize: function () {
        this._super();

        this.cookieMessages = $.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages');
        this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
            disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
        });

        if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
            customerData.set('messages', {});
        }

        $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
    },

    initObservable: function () {
        this._super()
            .observe('isHidden');

        return this;
    },

    RemoveMessage: function () {

        var el = $(this.selector);
        if (el.hasClass('fadeIn')) {
            el.toggleClass('fadeIn fadeOut');
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            el.hide()
        }, 2000);
    },

    isVisible: function () {
        return this.isHidden(!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages) || !_.isEmpty(this.cookieMessages));
    },

    onHiddenChange: function (isHidden) {
        var self = this;

        // Hide message block if needed
        console.log(isHidden);
        if (isHidden) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                self.RemoveMessage();
            }, 5000);
        }
        // reseting variable
        this.isHidden(false);
    },
});


});
```

Now i want to add functionality to hide messages on close button click.
I have seen [this solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/347829/add-close-button-to-messages-magento-2), all work fine, no problem.
But i want to use my custom function RemoveMessage from messages.js, for smoothness.
How can i it?